# Reference of table in the parent query from a sub subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, correlated-subquery, mysql-dependent-subquery

I want to perform a list of users and extract a list of contacts done by each one, grouped by type of item contacted, in one field. Something like this:

```
user_id, user_name, user_contact_views
100, john, 'a=21,b=22,c=3'
101, mary, 'a=53'
102, jack, 'b=13,c=5'
```

I have this query almost working

```
SELECT
u.id user_id,
u.name user_name,
(select group_concat(type_id_n_contacts)
 from (select CONCAT(item_type_id, '=', count(*)) type_id_n_contacts
        from item_contact ic
        where ic.user_id = u.id
        group by item_type_id) sq_type_id_n_contacts
) as user_contact_views
, ... -- Lots of fields
FROM user u
INNER JOIN -- Other tables, field, where and so on ignored
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT ...;
```

But I get

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'u.id' in 'where clause'
```

I cannot use u.id from the nested query and I would appreciate if you guys know any work arround to solve it. What about MySQL variables? How to get the value of u.id to a variable in the subsubquey to use ic.user_id = @user_id?

**Important note:** I have to use the subquery in the fields section. I can make the query work by creating a temp table in a JOIN with all precalculated users_id related with the count string (see Giulio answer). I know that, however there are too many fields to do it with the whole table of users and make a join unindexed afterwards. That's why I want MySQL perform the subquery only with the user_ids already filtered and limited by the WHERE and LIMIT, in the last phase of the query execution. I hope I explained myself.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide complete query and some information about joins, i think this can be done without using a sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your subquery in the join part:

```
    SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name,
     table_tmp.user_cont as user_contact_views,
    , ... -- Lots of fields
    FROM user u
    INNER JOIN
     (select group_concat(type_id_n_contacts) as user_cont, sub_user_id
     from (select CONCAT(item_type_id, '=', count(*)) type_id_n_contacts, ic.user_id as sub_user_id
            from item_contact ic
            group by item_type_id) sq_type_id_n_contacts
    ) as table_tmp ON table_tmp.sub_user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN -- Other tables, field, where and so on ignored
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY ...
    ORDER BY ...;
```

Comment: Thanks Giulo, but your query doesn't work. Nevertheless, what you mean is this JOIN:
LEFT JOIN
     (select group_concat(type_id_n_contacts) as user_cont, sub_user_id
     from (select CONCAT(item_type_id, '=', count(*)) type_id_n_contacts, ic.user_id as sub_user_id
            from item_contact ic
            group by item_type_id, user_id) sq_type_id_n_contacts
  group by sub_user_id) as table_tmp ON table_tmp.sub_user_id = u.id

Comment: Yes, i mean the join that you pasted in your comment. Obviously i could not try the query, i just wrote an example :)

Comment: It is unreadable, but I get your idea. I can make the query work by createing a temp table with all precalculated users_id related with the count string. I know that, however there are too many fields to do it with the hole table of users and make a join unindexed afterwards. Thats why I want MySQL perform the subquery only with the user_ids already filtered and limited by the WHERE and LIMIT, in the last phase of the query execution. I hope I explained myself.

Comment: Having MySQL variable whith the value of u.id could make the trick in the subquery with ic.user_id = @user_id, but I cannot make it! :-(

Comment: Yes, i understand your problem. Try to put a condition "WHERE ic.user_id = u.id " in the sub "SELECT FROM item_contact ic..." of my example. Maybe it can work